# How to find if the signals are in sync or out of sync with each other?

Tags: signal-analysis, correlation, time-series, real-time, waveform-similarity

[image]

Considering these are two signals over time, black and red.Following are some of the properties

1. Every Second a new data point is added over time . There is no control on the generation of the signals/how the signals are generated. Cannot nail down the signal generation under any function or logic.
2. Each of the signals has its own scale however the scale is always within 0-10 .
3. On visualisation both the signals looks similar at times and dissimilar at times.

## Question

1. How to find out if the red signal is moving in-sync with the black signal or is out of sync.
   Note - The signals are realtime in nature , the look-back might be a maximum of 60 seconds.
2. What is the correct approach to solve problems like this?
   I am looking for some direction here.

Edit - Use case

These are two bacterial growths over time . Once both the bacteria population are in sync or async is detected then some action is needed to be taken. This action has to be taken only within 60 seconds of their new movement else the experiment leads to certain implications. It might happen that in a span of 1 hour there are 200 actions taken , quite possible , but the timing of the action and instant when both bacteria's change their trend has to be within 60 seconds.

For example

sync detected - 11:20:36 , trend started- 11:19:47 action - decrease control temperature 

async detected -12:31:22 trend started- 12:30:24 action -increase temperature

Comment: why are you so strongly restricting your look-back time? 60 points isn't much...

Comment: because these data points are coming from IOT sensors and based on the sync or out of sync capability decisions are taken and so as to operate another pump or not. Therefore the look back is restricted

Comment: Don't quite follow – these sensors exist for more than 60s, don't they?

Comment: yes they do , let me explain the use case. These are two bacterial growths over time . Once both the bacteria population are in sync or async is detected then some action is needed to be taken. This action has to be taken only within 60 seconds of their new movement else the experiment leads to certain implications. It might happen that in a span of 1 hour there are 200 actions taken , quite possible , but the timing of the action and instant when both bacteria's change their trend has to be within 60 seconds

Comment: For example  
sync detected - 11:20:36 , trend started- 11:19:47 action - decrease control temperature
async detected -12:31:22 trend started- 12:30:24 action -increase temperature

Comment: wow, this is helpful, @Rai Bose! Would you please edit your question to include the use case – others will have a far easier time following your question, and understanding what "in sync" means to you, if they know your use case.

Comment: @MarcusMüller added the use case in the question as well

Comment: If it was me I would use "normalized cross-correlation" in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalization
I am presume a stochastic process; which I would have to think about to justify.
I think your  request would show but you have to examine it for special conditions.  Also you should build a computer model of what you planing to do and your imagined inputs conditions.   There is a resource for the model; next comment :)

Comment: Maybe I should have put this into an "Answer".   Anyhow, by controlling the variations, temperature/humidity,  using a DOE (Design Of Experiments) testing scheme will get the sensitivities and gain for system model good enough for a set-point situation where you never allow large deviations.  Last time I looked SAS had an excellent DOE design module l; including constraint.  The last is relevant for a lot of systems.